# MATLAB|OCTAVE - nonconformant arguments

Tags: math, octave

I have the following task for my exam and would be pleased if anyone can help me
[This is task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8UCA.png)

```
calculate
z=5x^2+y^2-4
x∈[−15,15]
y∈[−5,5]
```

it's required to have 20-20 dots on each of them. (to build graph)

What I tried?
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y396P.png)

```
y=-5:5;    
x=-15:15;    
z=5.*(x.^2)+(y.^2)-4;
```

I am getting this error:
error: `operator +: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x31, op2 is 1x11)`

thanks in advance

PS: gtu ylea

Comment: Try `y=(-5:5).';`.

Comment: have a look at the `linspace` command.

Comment: The reason Chris's fix works is because of implicit broadcasting. By having the vectors in different 'directions' the . operators will project them into a 2d gridspace and the math performed on that.  Prior to MATLAB 2016b that would only work in Octave. You would have had to use `bsxfun` or some operations with `meshgrid`.

Comment: yes linspace seems to be solution.